# Teradata Comaprison for Current and Previous Dates

Tags: teradata

I'm looking for Teradata SQL Query help for below scenario.

I have a table with customer id and trans date and amount fields and want to get the desired output with start and end dates with amount spent between those dates for each customer.

For the Start Date of first transaction i want to hard code as 2000-01-01

```
Custid   Date       Amount    

1        2014-10-11    $100
1        2014-11-01    $50
1        2015-01-05    $20
2        2016-01-01    $40
2        2016-05-01    $60
```

I Want output something like below

```
CustID   Start_Date   End_Date     Amount
1        2000-01-01   2014-10-11   $100
1        2014-10-11   2014-11-01   $50
1        2014-11-01   2015-01-05   $20
2        2000-01-1    2016-01-01   $40
2        2016-01-01   2016-05-01   $60
```

could someone please help on the query in Teradata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Window Functions to pull this off (Essentially this is like `Lag()` functionality in other RDBMSs):

```
SELECT
    CustId,
    COALESCE(MAX("Date") OVER (PARTITION BY CustId ORDER BY "Date" ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), DATE '2000-01-01') AS Start_Date,
    "Date" as End_Date,
    Amount
FROM
    yourtable;
```

---

Example in use:

```
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE mytable(
   Custid INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,"Date"   DATE  NOT NULL
  ,Amount VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
) PRIMARY INDEX (CustID) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO mytable(Custid,"Date",Amount) VALUES (1,'2014-10-11','$100');
INSERT INTO mytable(Custid,"Date",Amount) VALUES (1,'2014-11-01','$50');
INSERT INTO mytable(Custid,"Date",Amount) VALUES (1,'2015-01-05','$20');
INSERT INTO mytable(Custid,"Date",Amount) VALUES (2,'2016-01-01','$40');
INSERT INTO mytable(Custid,"Date",Amount) VALUES (2,'2016-05-01','$60');

SELECT
    CustId,
    COALESCE(MAX("Date") OVER (PARTITION BY CustId ORDER BY "Date" ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), DATE '2000-01-01') AS Start_Date,
    "Date" as End_Date,
    Amount
FROM
    mytable;

DROP TABLE mytable;

+--------+------------+------------+--------+
| Custid | Start_Date |  End_Date  | Amount |
+--------+------------+------------+--------+
|      1 | 1/1/2000   | 10/11/2014 | $100   |
|      1 | 10/11/2014 | 11/1/2014  | $50    |
|      1 | 11/1/2014  | 1/5/2015   | $20    |
|      2 | 1/1/2000   | 1/1/2016   | $40    |
|      2 | 1/1/2016   | 5/1/2016   | $60    |
+--------+------------+------------+--------+
```

---

Optionally you could use a correlated subquery in your `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT 
    CustId,
    COALESCE((SELECT MAX("Date") FROM myTable WHERE mt.CustId = CustID AND "Date" < mt."Date"), DATE '2000-01-01') AS Start_Date,
    "Date" AS End_Date,
    amount AS amount
FROM
    mytable mt;
```

---

Example in use:

```
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE mytable(
   Custid INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,"Date"   DATE  NOT NULL
  ,Amount VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
) PRIMARY INDEX (CustID) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO mytable(Custid,"Date",Amount) VALUES (1,'2014-10-11','$100');
INSERT INTO mytable(Custid,"Date",Amount) VALUES (1,'2014-11-01','$50');
INSERT INTO mytable(Custid,"Date",Amount) VALUES (1,'2015-01-05','$20');
INSERT INTO mytable(Custid,"Date",Amount) VALUES (2,'2016-01-01','$40');
INSERT INTO mytable(Custid,"Date",Amount) VALUES (2,'2016-05-01','$60');


SELECT 
    CustId,
    COALESCE((SELECT MAX("Date") FROM myTable WHERE mt.CustId = CustID AND "Date" < mt."Date"), DATE '2000-01-01') AS Start_Date,
    "Date" AS End_Date,
    amount AS amount
FROM
    mytable mt;


DROP TABLE mytable;

+--------+------------+------------+--------+
| Custid | Start_Date |  End_Date  | amount |
+--------+------------+------------+--------+
|      2 | 2016-01-01 | 2016-05-01 | $60    |
|      1 | 2014-11-01 | 2015-01-05 | $20    |
|      2 | 2000-01-01 | 2016-01-01 | $40    |
|      1 | 2014-10-11 | 2014-11-01 | $50    |
|      1 | 2000-01-01 | 2014-10-11 | $100   |
+--------+------------+------------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot JNevill. Appreciate your help. Saved me a lot of time.